la expersion join no se admite en sql access
Al ejecutar la siguiente consulta me error : "La expresión JOIN no se admite"
SELECT 0_Input_Presupuesto2025.*,
  Switch ([Macroservicio_Disponible] = "NO", "NO DISPONIBLE",
          [Macroservicio_Disponible] = "SI", Macroservicio1
         ) AS Macroservicio,
         [0_Input_Presupuesto2025.CEGE]&[0_Input_Presupuesto2025.Epigrafe]&[Macroservicio] AS Concatenacion_Macroservicio
FROM  0_Input_Presupuesto2025 LEFT JOIN 0_Imputacion_Macroservicio
ON Concatenacion = Concatenacion_CEGE_Epigrafe;


Diría que el FROM está mal, tiene que ser del tipo
Tabla1 LEFT JOIN Tabla2 ON Tabla1.CampoA=Tabla2.CampoB
Revisa tu FROM:
FROM 0_Input_Presupuesto2025 
LEFT JOIN 0_Imputacion_Macroservicio 
ON **0_Input_Presupuesto2025.CampoA = 0_Imputacion_Macroservicio.CampoB**;

